# Properties View Extension - PropertyContributor and PropertySource are different?

Tags: plugins, properties, workbench, propertysheet, tabbed-view

I am extending the Properties View by implementing a separate plug-in, which is defining tabbed property contributor/tabs/sections in its manifest.

The property contributor is an active workbench part. I have managed to get a simple section in a different tab (kind of Hello World), when the active workbench part is chosen. The next thing to do is to fill these sections with certain informations from the property source. But the property source I need to use isn't in the plug-in project of the contributor. I know where these are, but the plug-in project of the property source is not extending (supporting) the tabbed properties view. Only thing I get by clicking/choosing the property sources the basic list view of their properties.

So, the first question is: Is it possible? Will it work to define some workbench part as propertyContributor and in the same time use the properties of property sources in my propertySections from some other plug-in project than the workbench part?

As in the below link, they always use the same contributor (contributorId) for all the extensions; propertyContributor, propertyTabs and propertySections.

*Link: http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Tabbed-Properties/tabbed_properties_view.html

And the second question is: I it possible to get the properties of property sources in a tabbed view, even though their plug-in isn't extending/supporting the tabbed properties view?

Thanks a lot!